# XPages: Base64 array Error on richtext value

Tags: java, xpages

Trying to open an email document on my XPages application Only in some cases, i've this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad character exits in Base64 array at
>   com.ibm.trl.acf.impl.util.Base64Table.decode0(Base64Table.java:307) at
>   com.ibm.trl.acf.impl.util.Base64Table.decode(Base64Table.java:376) at
>   com.ibm.trl.acf.impl.util.ACFUtil.base64Decode(ACFUtil.java:210)
>   ......

Problem seems to do with the RichText control value, i have the property htmlFiter and htmlFilterIn set to "acf"

What could be the cause? How to resolve this?

**UPDATE**

When i check the source of the document on Noteclient the richtext value is with base 64 encoded

Comment: Hi, not sure have you check this answer as responded by @EJP. If you already using Java 1.8 ver, then use java.util.Base64.

Comment: try settings the filter to identify. acf does not work on big images

Comment: @ThomasAdrian  but when i copy the same document to another server, it will open with out any problem and there is no any big image on the richtext field